# How to show that infinitely many mixed Nash equilibriums exist in this 2 player game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have a simple two-player game

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& L & R \\ \hline
T & 0, 1 & 0,0 \\ \hline
B & 1,0 & 0,1\\ \hline
\end{array}

How can I find that this game has infinitely many mixed Nash equilibria? I know how to show it graphically, but is there a way to also show it just mathematically?

I calculated that:

- $EU(T)>EU(B)$ when $\pi_2<0$, $\pi_2$ is the probability that player 2 chooses $L$.
- $EU(L)>EU(R)$ when $\pi_1>\frac{1}{2}$, $\pi_1$ is the probability that player 1 chooses $T$.

How can I deduce from this that infinitely many mixed strategies exist?
Because all I can find is the pure NE $(B,R)$.

Answer (score 1):

If player 1 choses B then player 2 is guaranteed to choose R. So player 1 will get a payoff of zero no matter what.

Suppose that player 1 chooses T with probability $p$ and B with probability $1-p$. For any $p$, this is an optimal strategy for player 1.